# Routing with parameter issue in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am making simple employee list and detail demo into ReactJS. I have employee list component which shows list of all employee fetch from some dummy rest web service and shows on page.

```
class contactList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      employees: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.EmployeeList();
  }
  EmployeeList() {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(results => {
        this.setState({ employees: results })
        .catch(
          error => { console.log(error); }
        );
      });

  }
  onDelete(e) {

  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.employees);
    const persons = this.state.employees.map((item, i) => (
      <div>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <Link to={"/Contactdetails/" + item.id} >{item.name}</Link>
                <Route exact path={"/Contactdetails/:id"} component={Contactdetails}></Route>
              </td>
              <td>
                <button onClick={this.onDelete}>
                  Delete
                                </button>
              </td>
            </tr>

          </tbody>
        </table>
        {/* <Link to="/">Delete</Link> */}
      </div>
    ));

    return (
      <div id="layout-content" className="layout-content-wrapper">
        <div className="panel-list">{persons}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

I've shown all a tags with corresponding id(parameter) on the page. Issue when I click on link, it doesn't take me to detail page. In detail page, I kept alert as well in render method, but it is also not appearing, So, I think detailpage is not getting call.

```
class Contactdetails extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {

        };
    }
    componentWillMount(){
        alert("Helloo");
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log("props: ", this.props.match)
        this.EmployeeDetails();
    }

    EmployeeDetails() {
        fetch('http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(results => { this.setState({ employees: results }) });
    }
    render() {
        alert("Hello");
        return (
            <h2>Contact Details</h2>
        )
    }
};
```

StackBlitz link:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-f4eha2?file=Contactdetails.js

Comment: what is the url after you click the link?

Comment: /Contactdetails/1 - Something like this. I after I click, it changes the url, I could not see anything on page

Comment: please open the browser console some error may persist in it

Comment: understood why this is happening, check my answer.

Comment: @UbiquitousDevelopers: try with Danyal soultion that's the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have specified the Route with path `/contactDetails/:id` in ContactList component which won't be called if the Route isn't `contactList` and hence you don't see the ContactDetails component. You instead need to define your Routes like

```
  <Route path="/contactList" component={ContactList} />
  <Route exact path={"/Contactdetails/:id"} component={Contactdetails} />
  <Route path="/addContact" component={AddContact} />
```

[Working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-diqjn7?file=Menu.js)

Answer (score 2):

Add the details page route to your main router file rather than inside ContactList.js. This is because it will never get called since your application looks for routes from the main router file or page.

```
<Switch>
  // Your Routes
  <Route exact path={"/Contactdetails/:id"} component={Contactdetails} />
  // The '/Contactdetails' route after /:id route since it will other wise not call the above one
</Switch>
```

Answer (score 0):

In that case, you need to first implement the router which can register the routs of your app like

```
<Route path="/contactList" component={ContactList} />
<Route path="/addContact" component={AddContact} />
```

Please check details about it [React Router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/)

Comment: My other routing are working, only detail routing is not working. you can check stackblitz link as well. it should either work all or not all, if issue with router